# Odoo - Python exception while integrating Google Calendar

Tags: python, exception, google-calendar-api, odoo, python-dateutil

I have encountered an issue while synchronising the odoo calendar with google's one after integrating the `Google Calendar`'s module and allowing the API access.

The following exception is raised after clicking the `synch` button on odoo's calendar

```
    File "/opt/odoo/addons/calendar/calendar.py", line 1328, in _parse_rrule
data['day'] = r._bymonthday[0]

TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

The odoo version I am using is `v9`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Important observation :

This situation is specefic to odoo 9, it have been fixed since then. So if you are able to migrate your data from the current version to a later one the problem would not apear then. Otherwise, please follow carefully the below answer.

### 1. Explanation

The exception that is raised could be due to installed `python-dateutil`'s version.

Some attribute types in the `python-dateutil`'s `2.4.x` (and upper) versions have been modified from `list`to `set`. A good idea would be to downgrade `python-dateutil` version from the current to `2.2` where the attributes have the same expected type for the synchronisation.

This question have been asked, and answered, in the odoo's official forum. You can visit [this link](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-can-i-resolve-google-calendar-error-set-object-does-not-support-indexing-74641).

### 2. Solution

In order to solve this problem, you should follow the steps below :

1. Check `dateutil`'s current version
2. Downgrade `dateutil` version to `2.2` (if applicable)
3. Make sure that the module is downgraded
4. Restart odoo server
5. Test google calendar synchronisation

These steps are detailed below :

**2.1. Check `dateutil` version**

Go to the machine's command prompt (terminal), whatever may be the OS, and type the following commands :

```
$ python
>>> import dateutil
>>> dateutil.__version__
```

If the version is `2.4` the output would be :

```
'2.4.0'
```

**2.2. Downgrade `dateutil` version to `2.2`**

You better have `pip` installed in your machine so you can type :

```
$ pip install python-dateutil==2.2
```

This would automatically uninstall current version and install the `2.2` instead.

**2.3. Make sure that the module is downgraded**

Do the step **2.1** all over and make sure the output is :

```
'2.2.0'
```

**2.4. Restart odoo server**

If you have odoo installed as a service you can restart it as follows :

```
service odoo-server restart
```

or (for Windows) :

```
sc start odoo-server
```

Else, you'd have to `kill` the process (according to the used OS) that is running the odoo server, then go where the `odoo.py` (or `odoo-bin` for odoo `>= 10.0`) is located and run it again. (This is not recommended, it's better to run it as a service)

**2.5. Test google calendar synchronisation**

Go to odoo, open the `Calendar` application, then click the `Sync with Google` button and that should be it.

Comment: Wow, two years after this change and `odoo` still hasn't fixed their problem or stopped making use of the private interface?

Comment: It appears that this issue has been fixed in later versions of odoo, [according to the source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/36caadaf6a8c73eb0de6bdc44fb09adb75b96707/addons/calendar/models/calendar.py#L1242). The proper thing to do is to update Odoo, not downgrade dateutil.

Comment: I only forgot to specify that this was for odoo 9 I'll put an edit. Thank you for your constructive observation.
Although, it could be a little bit delicate to migrate the database from the 9th version to later ones due to the changes that have been made.